# Why do the texts of radio buttons fail to appear?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Why is it that the texts for the radio buttons fail to render when the following code runs:

```
<div id='sctices'></div>​

var result = [
               {"id":"G84","value":"Mman, J"},
               {"id":"G95","value":"Ekara, G"},
               {"id":"G98","value":"Gedala, PS"}
             ];


var key, count = 0;
for(key in result) 
{
  var btnId = result[key].id;
  var btnValue = result[key].value;

    var radio = $("<input></input>",
    {
         type: 'radio',
         name: 'gtice',
         class: 'radio-default',
         checked: false,
         value: btnValue,
         id: btnId,
         text: btnValue
    });

//radio.text(btnValue);// did not work
radio.insertAfter("#sctices");
radio.wrap("<div></div>");
}
```

Please help. Strangely, the text appears in generated source. Thanks

Comment: Or asked in a different way, how do I make the texts appear against these radio inputs?

Comment: Well, an `input` is a void, or self-closing, element; it has no closing `</input>` tag as it can't contain any text or child elements. Put the text into a `label` tag, and associate the `label` to the `input` using the `for` (or, in plain JS the `.htmlFor` (I *think*)) attribute of the `label` element.

Comment: @DavidThomas: Thanks, but with the code as var radio = $("<input>" ... it still does not work

Comment: No, because `input` elements *can't contain child-nodes* (except for `textarea`, which can accept text (but not child elements).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the `radio` input does not display any text. The general practice is to use a `label` element alongside it for that. Try adding this line:

```
var $label = $("<label></label>").text(btnValue).prepend(radio);
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pm7ZQ/)

Comment: More elaborate than mine ;) But I would add `for="btnId"`

Comment: `$("<label />", { 'for' : btnId}).text().prepend()`.

Comment: @DavidThomas Good point, although it's worth noting that if the `label` element wraps the radio `input` the hit area is inferred by the browser automatically.

Comment: Oh, I hadn't actually noticed that the `input` was wrapped by the `label`. Me and my pernickity ways... =)

Comment: Ah - the prepend wrapped the radio... Does give an issue with spacing in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version

Source looks cleaner in my opinion [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/T8KRd/)

```
var result = [
    {
    "id": "G84",
    "value": "Mman, J"},
{
    "id": "G95",
    "value": "Ekara, G"},
{
    "id": "G98",
    "value": "Gedala, PS"}
];


var key, count = 0;
for (key in result) {
    var btnId = result[key].id;
    var btnValue = result[key].value;
    var $div = $('<div/>');
    var $radio = $("<input/>", {
        type: 'radio',
        name: 'gtice',
        class: 'radio-default',
        checked: false,
        value: btnValue,
        id: btnId,
    });

    var $label = $("<label/>",{ 'for' : btnId}).text(btnValue);
    $("#sctices").append($div.append($radio).append($label));
 }
```

---

Result:

```
<div id="sctices">
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="gtice" class="radio-default" value="Mman, J" id="G84">
    <label for="G84">Mman, J</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="gtice" class="radio-default" value="Ekara, G" id="G95">
    <label for="G95">Ekara, G</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="gtice" class="radio-default" value="Gedala, PS" id="G98">
    <label for="G98">Gedala, PS</label>
  </div>
</div>
```